# Can you call a parent method that has been overridden in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

Haxe allows child constructor classes to call the parent's constructor using `super()`, but tying to use `super()` outside of the constructor method triggers an error.  Is it possible for a child to call a parent's method if that method has been overridden?

Hastily written example:

```
class Parent {
    var thing:Bool;

    public function someFunc(){
        if(this.thing){
           return "TRUE!";
        } else {
           return "FALSE!";
        }
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    var thing2:Bool;

    public override function someFunc() {
        if(this.thing2){
            return "TRUE!";
        } else {
            return someFunc(); //call to parent function? 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but instead of returning the string "TRUE!" you can also use real booleans in Haxe: `true` or `false`.

Comment: It's just a silly example : P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is possible with the `super` keyword.

```
public override function someFunc() {
    if (this.isWorking) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.someFunc(); 
    }
}
```

http://haxe.org/manual/types-class-inheritance.html

Answer (score 3):

super.someFunc() in the Child is what you want.

(super() always means the parent class' constructor, which can only be called from the child's constructor)